# how to parallelize single function in R?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

My question has two parts:

1) I want to run my function in parallel regardless of the code inside, is possible?e.g.

```
data("iris")
x.train <- iris[1:100,1:4]
y.train <- iris[1:100,5]
x.test <- iris[101:150,1:4]
y.test <- iris[101:150,5]

myfun<- function(x.train,y.train,x.test,y.test){
  library("e1071")
  model1 <- svm(x.train,y.train,type="c-classification")
  predc <<- predict(model,x.test)
  model2 <- svm(x.train,y.train,type="nu-classification")
  prednu <<- predict(model,x.test)   }
```

I want to parallelize this part:

```
myfun(x.train,y.train,x.test,y.test)
```

2) I also want to run the above function multiple times:

```
for i=1:10
  myfun(x.train,y.train,x.test,y.test)
```

Can you tell me how can I do these two parts in parallel in R?
PS: My original data is immense and I run over 10 classifiers, I really need do it in parallel.

Comment: Look at the foreach package and the parallel backends for it. There are some nice vignettes. However, you will need to avoid `<<-`, i.e., rewrite your function to follow R's paradigm of avoiding side effects.

Comment: @Roland, thanks for replying. `foreach` provide looping function for parallelizing, I just want to make `myfun` which is not `loop` run in multiprocessing. so far all parallel packages provide parallelized looping. Can you please show me a solution by code? thanks.

Comment: Parallelization is not magic. You need to have different tasks, which you can send to the CPUs. In your function you have two independent tasks. The API for loops is easiest to run these two tasks in parallel. However, if you want to run the function in a loop anyway, performance is better if you parallelize that loop.

Comment: @Roland, thanks. So I need to declare to run each `SVM` part in parallel. Can you give me a clue to do it? btw, why `<<-` is not suitable since I want to send to workspace? thanks again.